# What's the difference between the Airbnb and CouchSurfing experience for a host?

Tags: airbnb, couchsurfing

I have a spare bedroom and I'm wondering whether I should put it on Airbnb or CouchSurfing.

I'd like to know more about what it's like to host on both sites, to make a better decision.

Comment: @Tom Same poster, and they were advised to repost with a clearer scope.  Also, only answered questions count as dupes.

Comment: At least one difference comes to mind : on airbnb guest do pay the host, whereas they don't pay the host on couchsurfing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about providing services, not travelling

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AirBnb: You can host people in your house and they will pay you for it. You should have your house ready to receive guests, like a clean house, good services like air conditioning, heating, be attentive and polite with your guests. Even some hosts give complimentary services, like breakfast, free beer, water or other things.
It is like a little hotel with 1, 2 or 3 rooms. You charge for the services and you have an obligation for good service to them.
I would like to say, that you will have to pay taxes for the service.

Couchsurfing: You are inviting people to sleep in your house (sometime it can be just go for a walk with them, not just hosting).
In that case, you are not "obliged" to get anything ready. Otherwise, it would be very polite from you to have a clean house or good services, but it just depend on you an the guest should not complain for anything, as long as they are not paying for anything. Even sometimes, host can bring you a little present, cook for you or pay a dinner or for drinks if you go out together. But it just happens sometimes.

In both cases, you will be rated and shared the experience with the community.

Comment: +1 basically, in AirBnB, the strangers in your house are **paying customers**, in Couchsurfing they're **social guests**. One other practical difference: in AirBnB it's generally best to simply show them around the property, tell them a bit about the local area, then leave them alone. In Couchsurfing you'll probably want to socialise with them (that's kinda the point of doing it). I can't even begin to guess why someone down-voted this answer?!?! Madness.

Comment: To me, this seems rather obvious, but this answer covers the difference quite well.

Comment: Really, the answer depends on what you want—money or company (or both).  To further complicate things, consider http://BeWelcome.org or http://WarmShowers.org or http://WorkAway.info